# How to install specific apache version?

Tags: apache, apt-get, apt

I developed one module for apache 2.4 server, I want to test my module with different apache versions.

I installed apache2.4 using following command.
apt-get -y install apache2

Can I install previous apache versions using apt-get?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the package name with version number

```
apt-get install <packagename>=<complete version name>
```

The below command will show the list of versions

```
apt-cache showpkg <pachagename>
```